# Hadoop KMS with HDFS keystore: No FileSystem for scheme "hdfs"

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs, keystore

I have been trying to configure the Hadoop kms to use hdfs as the key provider. I follow the Hadoop docs for that matter, and I added the following field to my kms-site.xml:

```
  <property> 
      <name>hadoop.kms.key.provider.uri</name>
      <value>jceks://hdfs@nn1.example.com/kms/test.jceks</value>
      <description>
      URI of the backing KeyProvider for the KMS.
      </description>
  </property>
```

That route exists in hdfs, and I expect the kms to create the file test.jceks for its keystore. However, the kms failed to start due to this error:

```
ERROR: Hadoop KMS could not be started

REASON: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "hdfs"

Stacktrace:
---------------------------------------------------
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "hdfs"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.JavaKeyStoreProvider$Factory.createProvider(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderFactory.get(KeyProviderFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.server.KMSWebApp.contextInitialized(KMSWebApp.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

For what I could manage to understand, it seems that this error is because there is no FileSystem implemented for HDFS. I have looked up this error but it always refers to a lack of jars for the hdfs-client when upgrading, which I have not done (it is a fresh installation). I am using Hadoop 2.7.2

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Hadoop's Jira issue tracker [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15412). As the user [Wei-Chiu Chuang](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=jojochuang) pointed out, having the keystore in HDFS is not a valid use case. KMS can't use HDFS as the backing storage because each HDFS client file access would go through a loop of HDFS NameNode --> KMS --> HDFS NameNode --> KMS ....

So only the file based KMS can use keystore files on the local file system.